# De onde surgiu "vou dar um pulo ali e já volto"?

Tags: significado, expressões, origem-histórica

Eis que já ouvi essa expressão. Exemplos:

> - Vou dar um pulo ali e já volto!
> - Vamos lá Jon Snow! Deixa de manha! É um pulo! Logo estaremos de volta.

E num trecho  no livro [*Na palma da minha mão* (1998) de Leilah Assumpção](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=bks&q=%22Te%20chamei%20para%20dar%20um%20pulo%20ali%20pertinho%22&oq=%22Te%20chamei%20para%20dar%20um%20pulo%20ali%20pertinho%22&gs_l=serp.3...13625.16236.0.17348.2.2.0.0.0.0.406.471.1j4-1.2.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.0.0.CrkU5bh9_yY):

> Era um bonito entardecer suave. Te chamei para dar um pulo ali pertinho, na avenida Montaigne.

De onde surgiu “vou dar um pulo ali e já volto”?

Comment: Acklay, não tenho a certeza do que é que queres que expliquemos.  *Pulo* significa nos teus exemplos 'ida rápida'; vê [Aulete 3](http://www.aulete.com.br/pulo). Todas as outras palavras são usadas no seu sentido literal. Mas mesmo este sentido figurado de *pulo* compreende-se bem: se chegas a algum lugar num pulo, chegas muito rapidamente. Parece-me que a única coisa que podemos tentar ver é quando é que *pulo* aparece pela primeira vez com este significado na  língua escrita. Ou há mais algum outro aspeto que queiras ver explicado?

Comment: Não é uma expressão recente. Essa citação de «O Sertanejo», de José de Alencar, data de 1875: *"[André, dá um pulo lá embaixo, homem, e tira as mochilas dos cavalos](https://books.google.pt/books?id=vchcAAAAQBAJ&dq=O%20sertanejo&hl=pt-BR&pg=PT255&ci=112%2C241%2C768%2C102&source=bookclip)"*. Provavelmente há casos mais antigos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Dar um pulo a algum lugar*** significa ‘ir rapidamente a algum lugar e ficar lá só um tempinho’. A expressão vem no dicionários. Por exemplo, no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/pulo):

> **Dar um pulo a/até/em**
>   **1** Ir a algum lugar para uma visita ou estada rápida: *Vou dar um pulo à/até a/na farmácia.*

Esta expressão aparece na literatura já em 1853 e vem na continuidade de expressões relacionadas em que *pulo* já tem o sentido de ‘rapidez’: *fazer alguma coisa **de um pulo*** ou ***num pulo***; *de um pulo* caiu algo em desuso, *num pulo* continua bem vivo. Estas expressões podem ser usadas literalmente, isto é quando alguém pula mesmo sobre algo. No sentido literal usa-se, ou usou-se, sobretudo *de um pulo*, como neste exemplo de 1665 (negrito meu e grafia original em todas as citações):

> O tigre raivoso trabalhava pello tirar [um porco] do posto ; mas vendo que não aproveitavão suas diligencias, **saltoulhe de hum pulo nas costas** …
>   [Padre Manuel Godinho, *Relação do novo caminho que fez por terra, e mar, vindo da India para Portugal no anno de 1663”*, Lisboa, 1665.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=k1ZpAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA138&dq=%22hum%20pulo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh0NmDpNnWAhVF5xoKHavcBhs4MhDoAQj3ATAd#v=onepage&q=%22hum%20pulo%22&f=false)

Mas são usadas também figuradamente, para se indicar que se fez algo, especialmente ir, vir, levar, trazer, etc., muito rapidamente. Neste sentido usa-se sobretudo *num pulo*. Encontramos exemplos deste uso desde o século XVIII:

> Naõ lhes há de suceder perigo, **parte em hum pulo** a caza da Adella, para que me mande o vestido, e mais roupa, em que fallamos, e que seja tudo já sem a minima demora,
>   [*Jocozo acontecimento de huns noivos no dia do seu noivado*, Lisboa, 1787.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=E7JJAQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22hum%20pulo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh0NmDpNnWAhVF5xoKHavcBhs4MhDoAQhjMAg#v=onepage&q=%22hum%20pulo%22&f=false)
>
> Para seu cão de fralda, se he seu gosto ,
>   **N’um pulo , lhe trarei** o Caõ Cerbero
>   [Antonio Diniz da Cruz e Silva, *O Hyssope, poema heroi-comico*, Lisboa, 1808, p. 78.](https://archive.org/stream/ohyssopepoemaher00cruz#page/78/mode/2up/search/pulo)
>
> Parece que depois de tantos seculo temos **retrocedido de hum pulo** aos desenfreados tempos de Aristophanes
>   [“Noticias estrangeiras”, *Diario do Governo*, nº 24, Lisboa, Janeiro de 1822, p. 194.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=oO8vAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194&dq=%22retrocedido%20de%20hum%20pulo%22&source=bl&ots=ASDB9XlMfU&sig=WiNstzS-utm4QUJDisUuvgWeFY4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLo_-UsNnWAhWGtxoKHYAKDmsQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22retrocedido%20de%20hum%20pulo%22&f=false)

Em muitos destes usos, embora se diga apenas que se vai, vem, etc., num pulo, está implícito que se vai e volta em pouco tempo. Por exemplo, pouco interessaria que o homem trouxesse o cão Cérbero num pulo, se primeiro ficasse lá horas a fazer-lhe festinhas; a ideia é que eu vou agora e rapidamente estou de volta com o cão. E daqui se passa facilmente a *dar um pulo a algum lugar* com o sentido de ‘ir e voltar rapidamente’. Eis os exemplos mais antigos que encontrei:

> Pois não, tenham agora uma casa alugada para não receber vintem. Tenha paciencia, e estou aqui, **estou a dar um pulo lá cima á outra senhora**, que tambem se vai fazendo esquecida; derrete-se a fazer cortezias, rapapés, muito sorriso, mas lá a respeito de cobres [‘dinheiro’], nada.
>   [*O Jardim Litterario*, vol. 9, 1953.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=s4M3AQAAMAAJ&q=%22dar%20um%20pulo%22&dq=%22dar%20um%20pulo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQrILExtzWAhUD2xoKHQThB0sQ6AEIdzAM) (Mais [segundo excerto para completar.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=s4M3AQAAMAAJ&q=%22Est%C3%A1%20decidido%20vou%20la%20j%C3%A1,%20e%20d%C3%AA%20por%20onde%22&dq=%22Est%C3%A1%20decidido%20vou%20la%20j%C3%A1,%20e%20d%C3%AA%20por%20onde%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP5riMx9zWAhXEChoKHev5BmEQ6AEIKDAA))
>
> **Dê tambem um pulo a casa do mestre Jacyntho**, que lhe quero fallar quanto antes.
>   [José d’Almada, *Ambições d’um Eleitor* (peça representada em 1854), Lisboa, 1857, p. 6.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=WgQNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA6&dq=%22um%20pulo%20a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy4evK9d_UAhUL2xoKHVhACOIQ6AEIXDAJ#v=onepage&q=%22um%20pulo%20a%22&f=false)
>
> V. S. tem á mão papel e tinta para passar a contra-fé... senão **dou um pulo á venda** defronte.
>   [José de Alencar, *Mãi: drama em quarto actos*, Rio de Janeiro, 1865.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=6tMpAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA38&dq=%22dou%20um%20pulo%20%C3%A1%20venda%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUw4K4zNzWAhUEOxoKHcFFCR0Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22dou%20um%20pulo%20%C3%A1%20venda%22&f=false)